# Scrapy Pagination FormRequest

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape all of the comments from this page:
https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/comments/2479197624

There are two pages of comments, and I'm able to scrape the first page, but do not know how to make the scrapy Spider go to the second page to scrape those comments as well. This is my current code:

```
contributor_id = "".join(filter(str.isdigit, response.css('a.commentthread_author_link::attr(href)').get()))
        workshop_id_number = response.css('form.smallForm > input::attr(value)').get()

        if int(response.css('span.tabCount::text').getall()[1]) > 50:

            url = f'https://steamcommunity.com/comment/PublishedFile_Public/render/{contributor_id}/{workshop_id_number}/'

            headers = {
                'Accept':   'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding':  'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Accept-Language':  'en-US,en;q=0.5',
                'Connection':   'keep-alive',
                'Host': 'steamcommunity.com',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':    '1',
                'User-Agent':   'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0'
            }

            data = {
                "start": "1",
                "totalcount": "133",
                "count": "133",
                "sessionid": "d880ab2338b70926db0a9591",
                "extended_data": "{\"contributors\":[\"76561198401810552\",{}],\"appid\":289070,\"sharedfile\":{\"m_parentsDetails\":null,\"m_parentBundlesDetails\":null,\"m_bundledChildren\":[],\"m_ownedBundledItems\":[]},\"parent_item_reported\":false}",
                "feature2": "-1"
            }

            yield FormRequest(url, formdata=data, callback=self.parse_paginated_comments, dont_filter=True,)
```

How do I get the scraper to get to the next page?